# What is the probability $P\{X_1 \rm{~is ~largest}\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be three independent and mutually identically distributed random variabe with uniform distribution on [0,1]. What is the probability $P\{X_1 \rm{~is ~largest}\}$?

Comment: Interesting question, but the tag normal-distribution should be removed.

Comment: Isn't it simply $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability is $\frac{1}{3}$. This follows from the fact that the probability
 that two of the variables are the same is 0. Due to the symmetrical situation,
 the probabilies, that $X_1$ , $X_2$ and $X_3$ is the greatest are equal.